# splitting a 64-bit addition into two 32-bit additions

Tags: performance, algorithm, 64-bit

I'm working on an ultra-performance-intensive computational task. For adding-pairwise  two 32-bit integer arrays, could one, on a 64-bit architecture, treat two 32-bit values as a single 64-bit value, add them to their complement on the other array, then split them up again with a bitwise & operator. Obviously if there is an overflow, they will not be the same, but assuming there is none, will there be a problem? (And can you continue this to 16 and 8 bit additions?)

Does the behavior change for unsigned vs signed?

Comment: the behaviour of signed (2's complement) and unsigned addition is identical because they're the same action, but you interpret the result differently. You can split it all the way down to 1-bit numbers and ignoring overflow you would be doing XOR (which you can then pack together to a 32bit XOR without any difference).

Comment: Just make sure you never get a carry from the low-order addition into the high-order addition. Simple way: make sure each 32-bit number is positive and always less than (1<<30).

Comment: Bitshifting, or-ing and and-ing values together is going to be a lot slower than just adding them individually. If they're in adjacent memory locations, though, you could just treat them as a 64-bit integer and add them without any pre- or post- processing required.

Answer (score 2):

There's no difference between signed and unsigned - on two's complement machine it's just one instruction that doesn't know about the sign. Yes, you can safely do this trick *if there's no overflow risk* and you can do this for subparts of any lengths, for example, you can think that your 64-bit number holds two 13-bit numbers and one 38-bit number.

Comment: I think that's wrong if you have a negatively signed value in the bottom 32bits - e.g. -1. That's 0xFFFFFFFF, so if you add 2 to it you'd be guaranteed to overflow. So with signed numbers, you'd always have an overflow risk on the bottom 32bits

Comment: @Malcolm Box: Yes, but that's an overflow anyway, so it's out of the OP's question.

Comment: @sharptooth: the nitpick there being that `-1 + 2` is an *unsigned* overflow (well, wraparound), and an overflow as far as the relevant 2's complement CPU instruction is concerned, but not a *signed* overflow as far as the standard is concerned. The questioner said assume no overflow, but didn't specify whether to assume no signed overflow, no unsigned overflow, or both.

Comment: @Steve Jessop: Yes, I agree, of course I meant "overflow" in terms of processor, not in terms of C++. Btw the OP doesn't mention the language.

Comment: @sharptooth: sorry, I keep forgetting that I have "algorithm" in this bookmarked search as well as C and C++.

Comment: I had assumed that it meant "bit 32 of the result does not depend on bits 0-31 of the inputs".

Answer (score 2):

If you assume no overflow, you can do this down to single bits. Of course, 1+1 overflows. 
But in pratice, you either have overflow, or you really had 31 bit integers to start with.

One other thing: it only works on `unsigned` types. You can't have a sign bit in the middle of a 64 bit number.

But why do you care? If you're going "ultra-performance-intensive", use SSE. It will do parallel addition properly.

Comment: I guess there are limits; I'm not going to write it in assembler, though i guess there are some c extensions to do this. I'm actually doing branchy image processing work.I'd also rather not limit myself to a particular architecture unnecessarily.

Comment: @DanielOfTaebl : portability is not compatible with "ultra-performance-intensive". Choose one.

Comment: Perhaps "ultra" was too much. I'll go with "very".

Comment: @DanielOfTaebl If you have a good compiler, you might be able to get it to emit SSE instructions from portable C via the magic of auto-vectorization.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this, but it would only work for unsigned values. With signed 32bit integers, the sign bit is the high order bit, which causes overflow when adding.

You probably don't need to do this - if your native C compiler isn't giving the performance you need, then look at using the vector operations (MMX, SSE etc) that do this sort of vector operations extremely efficiently.